# MS Access does not display hyperlink in linked Sharepoint list (image)

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I created a sharepoint list from within MS access
From within Sharepoint, I added an 'image' column to that list
I shared the Sharepoint list for other users
ANOTHER PERSON used their phone to open the sharepoint list.  Took a picture
That image successfully displays in Sharepoint (viewing the list from sharepoint)
If I save & open that sharepoint list in Excel, I can see the hyperlink to the image.  This is what I desire and expect
However, when I link to the sharepoint list from within Access (remember, I created the list from Access and therefore should have permissions), the new image column is available, but there is NO DATA in the column (I expect the hyperlink to the image here
Furthermore, I inspected the contents of all the sharepoint fields using VBA to list the field and contents.  Here are the results of that inspection:

ID - 1
Title - 
Compliance Asset Id - 
StockID - 1
StockItem - P12345
WarrantImage - 
Content Type - Item
App Created By - 
App Modified By - 
Workflow Instance ID -
File Type - 
Modified - 5/4/2021 11:53:44 PM
Created - 5/4/2021 11:43:18 PM
Created By - XXXXXXXXXXX
Modified By - YYYYYYYY
URL Path - sites/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/Lists/SHAREPOINT_WARRANTS/1_.000
Path - sites/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/Lists/SHAREPOINT_WARRANTS
Item Type - 0
Encoded Absolute URL - 
https://ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/sites/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/Lists/SHAREPOINT_WARRANTS/1_.000

(XXXXX, YYYYYY, ZZZZZZ: obfuscating data)

In the list of fields above, I expect to have a value in the 'WarrantImage' field (again, I expect a hyperlink)

Comment: Exactly what data type is WarrantImage field?

Comment: Maybe adding the field from Access side would have worked?

Comment: From Sharepoint, the column was an 'image' column as stated above.  From within Access, it shows as a 'short text'.  However, in Excel, the length of the hyperlink is clearly larger than 255.

Comment: There is no 'image' data type. Field would have to be long text, short text, hyperlink, or attachment type.